# Excel Q; How do I return 2 values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am needing some help with a formula to help me return an answer on 2 separate sheets.

In worksheet 2 I want to check if the ID number in coloumn A is listed anywhere in worksheet 1 in coloumn A. If it is I want it to say UNPAID if it isn't in there it should say "PAID".

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. `COUNTIF` like:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(sheet1!A:A,A2)>0,"UNPAID","PAID")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to see if the value exists in the other worksheet.

Wrap that in an [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function that [checks for an error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665).

If there is an error, in your IF formula, put the "UNPAID" value otherwise put "PAID".